# Strange result while calculating average time

Tags: python, time

I have this method whose purpose is to take in a set of score objects, extract a run time from them with a get_run_time_str() method, and then calculate the average of all the run times. The get_run_time_str() method returns the times in the string format 'mm:ss'. The procedure I currently have in place is to take the 'ss' part of the time, convert it to a decimal (base 10), concatinate it to the number of minutes and perform the averaging calculation, then convert it back to a seconds (base 60) format.

This procedure is working for most sets of data that I currently have. I have confirmed this with an online tool that averages times. However there are some pieces of data that, for whatever reason, give me a seconds value that is greater than 60. Here is the code (I realize that I do need to try and clean up the type conversions a little):

```
def get_avg_two_mile(self, scores):
    sum_time = 0
    length = len(scores)
    for score in scores:
        stripped_score = score.get_run_time_str().replace(':', '')
        seconds = int(stripped_score[2:])
        seconds = str(seconds/float(60))
        stripped_score = float(stripped_score[:2] + '.' + seconds[2:])
        sum_time = sum_time + stripped_score
    avg = sum_time/float(length)
    decimal = str(avg).split('.')[1]
    decimal = str(int(decimal) * 60)
    avg = str(avg).split('.')[0] + ':' + str(decimal)[:2]
    return avg
```

When a data set containing the times: '16:34', '16:18', and '18:39' is used, I should get an average time of 17:07 according to the online tool I am using. Instead however I am getting '17:70'. Not very valid there. Once again most data sets return a time that is accurate, but there are some instances in which this issue is occurring.

The code to accomplish this is a little messy, and certainly more messy than it would be to do this procedure by converting the minutes to seconds and averaging from there, however this method did not seem to work either when I ran it through a prompt.

Any ideas? And also would this procedure be easier using any built-in python time related classes?

Comment: `And also would this procedure be easier using any built-in python time related classes?`  This procedure would be easier if you just skipped the string manipulations entirely.  Don't make some kind of `mm:ss` thing, then try to extract seconds from it, and jump through hoops manipulating it.  Just get the total seconds at the earliest possible point, and do your calcs with that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the fact that there are 60 seconds per minute. So, averaging `17.10` and `16.50` gives `16.80`.

You should carry out your calculation in seconds. Then:

```
stripped_score = 60 * float(stripped_score[:2]) + float(seconds[2:])
```

After this your average time string can be formed as:

```
"{:02d}:{:02d}".format(avg / 60, int(avg % 60))
```

(You are right, you need to clean it up a bit. You might even want to have a look at the `time` and `datetime` modules, if you need to perform more calculations with time.)